# Animations in PDF made with LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations, animate

I am starting with `animate` package on LaTeX, and I want combine the animations and matrices from math, and make a electronic book for matrices with animated solutions of matrix.

I was trying make simple animation, but without results. I don't know where it stops, but I think I am doing it bad way.

I don't know how to do it, if with `\newframe` or `\multiframe` command, if I want some arrows, transformations, paths. I think I will need something like template, because what I need to do is simple and only about matrices. But I don't know how to do it step by step.

Here is the code what I am trying to do. 1st I want to add arrow into animation. Just 2frames changing. What should I change and how?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}

%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{fullpage,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{i} 
\setcounter{i}{0}
\begin{animateinline}[palindrome,controls]{1}
\multiframe{2}{i=0+1}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (matrix) [matrix of nodes]
    {
            1 & 1 & 3  \\
            2 & 1 & 5  \\
            3 & 1 & 6  \\
            };

        \draw[thick,red,->] (matrix-1-1) |- (matrix-2-3);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{animateinline} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple two-frame animation, as requested:

```
\documentclass[margin={10 1 10 0}]{standalone}
%\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
%\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{animateinline}[step,controls]{1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes]
      {
        1 & 1 & 3  \\
        2 & 1 & 5  \\
        3 & 1 & 6  \\
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \newframe
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes]
      {
        1 & 1 & 3  \\
        2 & 1 & 5  \\
        3 & 1 & 6  \\
      };
      \draw[thick,red,->] (magic-1-1) |- (magic-2-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{animateinline}
%\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you :) but it's not a problem, then it's not Beamer? It works, and it's enough I think. Now I know how to do animations. So if I want to show how to find determinant of matrix, i must to write every animation every step in \`newframe`? Or can I use  \`multiframe` function somehow and make it faster and more general for the same size of matrix?

Comment: `\multiframe` is intended for continuously changing parameter(s), such as i=1,2,...,99, inside the frames. I guess that start and end positions of the arrows will change erratically from frame to frame to demonstrate determinant calculation. Thus,  you will have to explicitly build every frame and use `\newframe` for separation.

Comment: Oh Ok then :) this is info which I need :) thank you for help really. I can't move, cause it's new language for me. Now it's only a lot of work, so I think it will be ok without bugs :)

Comment: @Ján: would you please consider accepting this as the correct answer to your above question (click checkmark on the left)?

Comment: Done :) sorry I am new :) I will know for next time

Comment: No problem, just to point upvoters in the right direction ;) .

Answer (score 7):

A `fragile` frame helps:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{animateinline}[step,controls]{1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes]
      {
        1 & 1 & 3  \\
        2 & 1 & 5  \\
        3 & 1 & 6  \\
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \newframe
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes]
      {
        1 & 1 & 3  \\
        2 & 1 & 5  \\
        3 & 1 & 6  \\
      };
      \draw[thick,red,->] (magic-1-1) |- (magic-2-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```