# LaTeX matrix Animations

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, animations

Hello I am doing Matrix animations. So i edited this question, so maybe it will be ok. This is what i got. I am trying to do animation. Now i know, then all frames in animation will be like 1st one, so i need to set 1st frame, or use `\useasboundingbox`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,upref,indentfirst,graphicx,eucal,makeidx}
\usepackage{animate}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}


    \begin{example} Zistite, pre aké reálne čísla $x,y$ platí
\break

\begin{animateinline}[palindrome,controls]{2} 

    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \matrix (magic) [
    matrix of math nodes,
    left delimiter=(,
     right delimiter=)
    ] at (0,0)
    {
    2x+5y & 4 \\
    9 & 2y+1\\ 
    };

    \node at (2.2,0) {=};

    \matrix (magic2) [
    matrix of math nodes,
    left delimiter=(,
    right delimiter=)
    ] at (4*\myunit,0)
    {
    12x+9 & 4 \\
    9 & 3\\ 
    };

    \matrix (magic3) [
    matrix of math nodes,
    left delimiter=(,
    right delimiter=)
    ] at (0,-2)
    {
    12x+9 & 4 \\
    9 & 3\\ 
    };
    \draw[line width=0.2cm,,color=red,line cap=round, opacity=0.5, line join=round] (magic-1-1) to (magic-2-1);


\end{tikzpicture}
\newframe
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \matrix (magic) [
        matrix of math nodes,
        left delimiter=(,
        right delimiter=)
        ] at (0,0)
       {
        2x+5y & 4 \\
        9 & 2y+1\\ 
        };
    \node at (2.2,0) {$=$}; 


    \matrix (magic2) [
    matrix of math nodes,
    left delimiter=(,
    right delimiter=)
    ] at (4*\myunit,0)
    {
    12x+9 & 4 \\
    9 & 3\\ 
    };
      \draw[line width=0.2cm,,color=red,line cap=round, opacity=0.5, line join=round] (magic-1-1) to (magic-2-1);
    %  \draw [BarreStyle=blue] (magic-1-1.west)  to (magic-2-1.east) ;


    \end{tikzpicture}

    \newframe
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \matrix (magic) [
        matrix of math nodes,
        left delimiter=(,
        right delimiter=)
        ] at (0,0)
       {
        2x+5y & 4 \\
        9 & 2y+1\\ 
        };
    \node at (2.2,0) {$=$}; 


    \matrix (magic2) [
    matrix of math nodes,
    left delimiter=(,
    right delimiter=)
    ] at (4*\myunit,0)
    {
    12x+9 & 4 \\
    9 & 3\\ 
    };
    \draw[line width=0.2cm,,color=red,line cap=round, opacity=0.5, line join=round] (magic-1-1) to (magic-2-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}     

    \matrix (magic3) [
    matrix of math nodes,
    left delimiter=(,
    right delimiter=)
    ] at (-4*\myunit,-2)
    {
    12x+9 & 4 \\
    9 & 3\\ 
    };
    \draw[line width=0.2cm,,color=red,line cap=round, opacity=0.5, line join=round] (magic-1-1) to (magic-2-1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{animateinline}
\end{example}
```

If you turn on the animation from this code, you can see 3 frames. 1st is the correct one i think. But instead the 3rd matrix under these 2 i want to write solutions of problem, and animate it. I think its still best method via Nodes, and matrix.

```
% \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
  %  nodes in empty cells]{
   % \quad & 1.\quad (x)(Q\supset Fx) & \\
   % & 2.\quad Q\supset Fx & \textrm{I,\textbf{UI}} & \\
   % & 3.\quad Q \\
   % & 4.\quad Fx & 2, 3, \textrm{ M.P.}\\
   % & 5.\quad (x)Fx & 4, \textrm{ \textbf{UG}} \\
   % & 6.\quad Q\supset(x)Fx & 3-5, \textrm{ C.P.} \\
   % & 7.\quad \parbox[t]{2.9cm}{%
```

this is not what i actually want, but its example.. I will use something from this code, but its only example.

then i will need to add some decorations. I found library matrix.skeleton, but i have problem while using it.. i use tikzpackage/matrix.skeleton, but mactex respond with error about not found libraries..

code is working w/o errors, buts still a lot of erors.

[Link to my 1st question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357643/animations-in-pdf-made-with-latex/358583?noredirect=1#comment883277_358583) Maybe it will help you to imagine my problem better.

Comment: Please add a minimal working example(MWE) http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that , with `\documentclass` ... `\end{document}`